# Get corresponding field elements with an array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table like with columns `photo_x` and `combine` and other fields.
`photo_x` is unique for each row. Now I have an array of `photo_x` values like `["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"]` as input, I want to get the corresponding `combine` field in the same row as output (which is an array).

I could use the following code to achieve the task, but is there a more concise method?

```
combine_field_values=[]
for name in ["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"]:
    combine_field_values.append(df_train[df_train['photo_x']==name]['combine'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `isin` with `Categorical`

```
s=df_train.loc[df_train['photo_x'].isin(["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"]),['combine','photo_x']]

s.photo_x=pd.Categorical(s.photo_x, ordered=True,categories=["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"])

s.sort_values(photo_x).combine.values
```

Comment: Does `isin` guarantee the order of the output array values is corresponding to the input array values?

Comment: @william007 sort after that .`df_train.sort_values('photo_x').loc[df_train['photo_x'].isin(["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"]),'combine'].values`

Comment: but the input array values (i.e., `["a.jpg","b.jpg", "c.jpg"]`) are not guaranteed to be sorted